# How to design 1:1 and 1:M relation

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I have the following situation:
-One customer can have exactly one service
-One service can take place in various places

I want to use normalization as Service names change (so one customer should have a FK to Service table?). I cannot imagine how the 1:1 will be maintained in this situation (I am awake for 24 hours and barely think but need to finish it)

I am asking as I have read here that 1-1 could always be one table, one object. But I believe it is not the case, e.g. in the example I gave - customer has just one service but the service name could change, so would it be correct to put into Customer table just a FK referencing the Service?

Answer (score 1):

> One customer can have exactly one service

"Can" implies a 0,1:1 relation.  You put a nullable foreign key referencing the Service table row in the Customer row.

> One service can take place in various places

For an n:m relationship, where n can be one, you create a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) that holds the keys of the Service table and the Place table.

```
ServicePlace
------------
Service ID
Place ID
```

The primary (clustering) key is both the Service ID and the Place ID.  If a place can have more than one service, you also create an index on Place ID and Service ID.